# Why are FB and Messenger app reactivated after restarting the phone?

Tags: applications, reboot, facebook, android-12, facebook-messenger

I only use FB Lite and the Messenger Lite app on my phone, so FB and the Messenger app are useless to me.

However, they cannot be uninstalled, only deactivated.

But I found out that after restarting both apps are reactivated. Of course, Android isn't Windows, so I don't need to restart it often (basically almost not at all), but it's still annoying.

Also, it didn't do this on the previous phone, but there was One UI, so it's probably related to "stock" Android (specifically version 12)

Please help

Thank you

PS. The problem phone is a [T-Phone](https://www.gsmarena.com/t_mobile_revvl_6-11937.php), but like I said, it's probably purely OS related.

Comment: How (command or action) have you disabled those pre-installed apps?

Comment: @Robert Settings -> Apps -> See all 132 apps (under Recently opened apps) -> Facebook -> Button DISABLE (between OPEN and FORCE STOP). Of course, before deactivating I stopped the app and cleared cache and data.